# Representation of streaming data using GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I want to represent streaming data using gnuplot. I tried it to plot using commands like 'replot','pause' and 'reread'. But its too slow and weird when data set is so large and similar.Is there any other way to plot streaming data

Comment: I doubt that you want `reread` as that causes gnuplot to reprocess the script, not the data.  `pause` is somewhat akin to `sleep` in other languages although you can `pause` until mouse commands or whatever.  `replot` or `refresh` is what you want -- there's no way (that I know of) to update the data that you've already given gnuplot.  You just need to give it new data and let it read the whole dataset in again.

Comment: It's worth asking what you're trying to do.  Your screen resolution is somewhere on the order of 2000x1000, and the gnuplot window only takes a small portion of that.  Realistically speaking, it's pretty much useless to plot anything bigger than 500x500 unless you've set the size of the terminal to be really big.  How big is you dataset?

Comment: We have got an input file which is growing (size more than 2GB). Using these commands we are able to plot streaming data, but when data set grows plot is getting congested..

Answer (score 1):

[feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot) is a Perl wrapper script around Gnuplot which does exactly what you describe using `replot`. It has a realtime streaming mode with option `--stream`. The documentation has an example where a live graph of bandwidth use of a network interface is drawn. If some option you need is not directly supported by feedgnuplot, you can sitll pass options through to gnuplot, so all drawing styles, axis settings etc are supported.